# Confused for taking up job in Information Security? please help me

Tags: career, soc

I am a fresher computer science graduate from India , I always wanted to pursue career in Information Security and interested in VAPT. But company I am selected in is giving me Security Operations Center Analyst (SOC analyst) profile. I am confused ,should I take it or wait for other opportunities in VAPT(vulnerability assessment and penetration testing) ?

Thank you
Waiting for your reply

Answer (score 2):

I would advise taking the job. Security is a difficult field to get into without experience, and a few years of security operations experience will make you much better qualified for penetration testing jobs that may become available.